pyaudio produces no sound when using explicit device
This code results in no sound output. Neither it sounds nor is indicated anywhere.
from contextlib import suppress
from typing import Mapping

import pyaudio
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

freq: float = 130.0

p: pyaudio.PyAudio = pyaudio.PyAudio()


def main() -> None:
    stream: pyaudio.Stream
    info: Mapping[str, str | int | float] = {
        "index": 0,
        "name": "HDA Intel PCH: ALC892 Digital (hw:1,1)",
        "maxInputChannels": 0,
        "maxOutputChannels": 2,
        "defaultSampleRate": 44100.0,
    }
    stream = p.open(
        format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
        channels=1,
        rate=round(info["defaultSampleRate"]),
        output=True,
        output_device_index=info["index"],
    )
    phase: NDArray[np.float32] = np.linspace(
        start=0.0,
        stop=2.0 * np.pi,
        num=round(info["defaultSampleRate"]),
        endpoint=False,
        dtype=np.float32,
    )
    wf: NDArray[np.float32] = np.sin(phase * freq)

    # about 140 seconds of sound
    with suppress(KeyboardInterrupt):
        for _ in range(100):
            stream.write(wf.tobytes())
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()


main()

p.terminate()

The info value is actually what p.get_device_info_by_index(0) gives.
However, when I use other info values, corresponding to pulse (#9 for me) and default (#10) devices, the same code works fine. The sine is emitted via the same physical device as I specifically set earlier. With a USB sound card, it's the same: explicitly, it's silent, but when I set it as the default device, it works.

stderr shows the same errors regardless of the device:
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1377:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:5205:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5728:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1377:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:5205:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5728:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1377:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5205:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5728:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline:CARD=0,DEV=0
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1377:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5205:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5728:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline:CARD=0,DEV=0
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1377:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5205:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5728:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1377:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.modem.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5205:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5728:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:404:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:404:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1036:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:481:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:481:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock

All of them are from pyaudio.PyAudio().

# lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                                LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:        24.2.1
Codename:       Yonada

$ python -c "import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))"
Python 3.12.7 (main, Oct  1 2024, 11:15:50) [GCC 14.2.1 20240910] on linux

